# Appending text to each line in multi-line cell Prefix and Suffix

Tags: microsoft-excel

i am trying to add in a prefix and suffix on each line in a multiline cell

The existing column might look something like (where an extra line break is used to separate cells):

I'd like to turn this

```
------ cell 1 ----
John 
James 
Jenna 
Johnny 
Jimmy 
------ cell 2 ----
Arron
Anne 
------ cell 3 ----
Mark
marc
Mathew
```

Into this:

```
------ cell 1 ----
<li>John</li> 
<li>James</li> 
<li>Jenna</li> 
<li>Johnny</li> 
<li>Jimmy</li> 
------ cell 2 ----
<li>Arron</li>
<li>Anne</li> 
------ cell 3 ----
<li>Mark</li>
<li>marc</li>
<li>Mathew</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly awkward way of doing it. Excel may not be the best software for this task.

I have the original names lists in Column D.

Then in E I have '0'.
In F-S (allowing for up to 15 names) I have dragged across

```
=IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),$D2,E2+1),LEN($D2))
```

This finds the line breaks and lists their locations. So for the first row, the data should say:

```
0    6    13    20    28    34    34    34    34 etc
```

Then we can put the `<li></li>` around the names. In columns T I put:

```
=IFERROR("<li>"&RIGHT(LEFT($D2,F2-1),F2-E2-1)&"</li>"& CHAR(10),"")
```

and dragged across to column AH. Now we have the names like this:

```
<li>James </li>    <li>Jenna </li>    <li>Johnny </li>   <li>Jimmy</li>
```

We can then concatenate these in the final cell in AI:

```
    =T2&U2&V2&W2&X2&Y2&Z2&AA2&AB2&AC2&AD2&AE2&AF2&AG2&AH2
```

Also, turn on Wrap Text for the final cells.